reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed DURING response - After 90 seconds
There is an issue when downloading a large file (which take some minutes to complete).
The endpoint returns 200, but after around 90 seconds waiting the download the connection is prematurely closed.
DEBUG 6 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] r.n.r.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider    : [ecd64cf4-1, L:/* ! R:*] onStateChange(GET{uri=*, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xecd64cf4, L:/*! R:*]}}, [response_incomplete])
ERROR 6 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [de66232f-2] Error [reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed DURING response] for HTTP GET "*", but ServerHttpResponse already committed (200 OK)
TRACE 6 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] o.s.h.s.r.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter      : [de66232f-1, L:/*:3000 - R:/*:32383] Failed to complete: Connection prematurely closed DURING response
ERROR 6 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [de66232f-1, L:/*:3000 - R:/*:32383] Error finishing response. Closing connection

reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed DURING response
     Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
 Error has been observed at the following site(s):
...
[ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]


reactor-netty-http: 1.0.39
spring-boot: 2.7.18
Java 11 (Also happens with Java 17)

I tried this config changes but had no success also:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        pool:
          type: disabled
          max-idle-time: 600000
          max-life-time: 6000000

Also tried to upgrade Spring Boot and Java.
Nothing worked.

The configuration you posted is dedicated to Spring Cloud Gateway!. Your download happens using a gateway route ? Can you provide the associated code or route configuration ? Have you tried the download with another client (curl, postman, etc.) to ensure the problem does not come from upstream service ?

This project has Spring Cloud Gateway.
The download happens using routes and the issue happens even by postman.
This is the route config:
gateway:       routes:         - id: api-v1           uri: http://localhost:8080           predicates:             - Path=/events/core/version1/**             - Header=isVersion1Enabled, enabled
